# How can I make a TTS bot similar to KDBot with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, text-to-speech

Hi I am a begginer and i have a problem with my code. when I use the command for the first time the bot enters the voice channel and it works perfect, but when using the command again it no longer works. I have tried disconnecting the bot every time I use the command and it works, but it is not what I really want, if the bot is already connected to the channel I need it to play the audio as kdbot does. Can somebody help me?

```
@bot.command()
async def tts(ctx,*, text:str):
    global gTTS
    language = "es-us"
    user = ctx.author
    speech = gTTS(text=text,lang=language,slow=False)
    speech.save("audio.mp3")
    channel = user.voice.channel
    
    try:
        vc = await channel.connect()
    except:
        print("Already connected")
        #vc = discord.VoiceClient(bot,channel)
        #await vc.connect(reconnect=True,timeout=4)

    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3'), after=None)
    counter = 0
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    duration = audio_len(cwd + "/audio.mp3")
    while not counter >= duration:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
    #await vc.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your bot is in a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.VoiceChannel), it already has a [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice#discord.VoiceClient) that you can get:

```py
from discord.utils import get
[...]
voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```py
@bot.command()
async def tts(ctx,*, text:str):
    global gTTS
    speech = gTTS(text=text, lang="es-us", slow=False)
    speech.save("audio.mp3")

    voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice:
        voice = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('audio.mp3'), after=None)

    counter = 0
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    duration = audio_len(cwd + "/audio.mp3")
    while not counter >= duration:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
```